# Pull To Refresh without FlatList

Tags: react-native

I have a View that renders dynamic cards from an API

```
<View>
 <Card>1</Card>
 <Card>2</Card>
 <Card>3</Card>
</View>
```

Is there a way to do a pull-to-refresh on this view?

Make a call to the server and refresh this view without a FlatList component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React-Native's `RefreshControl` can only be applied to a `ScrollView`. (Note that a `FlatList` is actually a `ScrollView`).

So wrap your `<Card />`'s in a `<ScrollView>` rather than a `<View>` and you can apply the `RefreshControl` to it as seen in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#refreshcontrol).

Here is an example Snack for you: https://snack.expo.io/Hk606OYKM

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Working like a charm, Thank You

Comment: This works, thanks @MattyK14